# How to remove a tuple on condition

Tags: python

I have 2 lists:

```
list1 = ["Alex", "John", "Bill", "Tom", ]

list2 = ["Paid", "Not Paid", "Paid", "Paid"]
```

I need to join them to have key - value pair and remove that pair that has "Not Paid" in it.

If I do:

```
list3 = zip(list1, list2)
print(*list3)
```

I get:

```
('Alex', 'Paid') ('John', 'Not Paid') ('Bill', 'Paid') ('Tom', 'Paid')
```

Now I need to remove the ('John', 'Not Paid') value. and put what is left in unzipped list.

How can I do that and is the 'zipping' approach good one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insted of computing the whole result and then correct it, compute directly the desired object.

```
size = len(list1)
res = []
for i in range(size):
    if list2[i] == "Paid":
        res.append( (list1[i], list2[i]) )
print(res)
```

Running this code given list1 and list2 as in your example the output is

```
[('Alex', 'Paid'), ('Bill', 'Paid'), ('Tom', 'Paid')]
```

N.B. *You did not specified the dimension of the two lists, but looking at your example I assume they have the same lenght, also you wrote key-value that is used in general for map objects like dictionary in Python, but the example shows a list of tuples, so I assume this one is the wanted result.* If you want to compute a dictionary the code is slightly different.

```
size = len(list1)
res = {}
for i in range(size):
    if list2[i] == "Paid":
        res[list1[i]] = list2[i]
print(res)
```

Now the output is

```
{'Alex': 'Paid', 'Bill': 'Paid', 'Tom': 'Paid'}
```

Finally as pointed out by **Mad Physicist** in comments, the code can be written in a more compact way by means of *comprehension*

```
res = [item for item in zip(list1,list2) if 'Not' not in item[1]]
```

In this way we get a list of tuples as in first code snippet, to make it a dictionary instead:

```
res = { k:v for (k,v) in zip(list1, list2) if 'Not' not in v }
```

Comment: Now write that as a comprehension: `res = [item for item in zip(list1, list2) if 'Not' not in item[1]]`

Comment: Yes that is the most Pythonic way to write it, but I wanted to provide a solution that emphasizes on the logic, and with indentetion I think the goal is achieved.

Comment: This works indeed but what does item[1] stand for?

Comment: It is the second element of each tuple generated by the zip function, so in this case item[1] can be either 'Paid' or 'Not Paid' because the second element is taken from list2.

Answer (score -1):

since tuples cannot be changed, only way is to create a new tuple that doesn't contain element.

1. firstly , convert tuple to a list(mutable).
2. use the list,remove() method to remove the item from list.
3. convert the list back to tuple.

Comment: This is not relevant to the question